# How is a Jew to learn laws according to his custom

Tags: halacha, minhag

I am wondering a Jew is supposed to learn the laws of Judaism in a matter that applies to Jews particulary. I would like to use myself to exemplefy my point. I am a Sephardic and did not find any Sephardic Shulchan Aruch classes. Without going on too much about myself, however, I did find a course from a Rabbi named Rabbi Yosef Shusterman. The thing about this is that he is Chabad and talks about issues from a Chabad halachik standpoint sometimes. Are there Sephardic books that take the Shulchan Aruch and talk about it from a Sephardic halchic standpoint, since this would be much less confusing for me. Now this isn't only for me, as the same could be said about almost all other groups aswell.

Comment: Is the question: is there a list, or way to find out exactly which halachic work one must follow for each minhag, and classes that offer this? I doubt it by the way. There are broad answers, and many minhagim are easy, but some are really not. Speaking from personal experience!

Comment: Yes that was exactly my question. I did find a series by Rabbi Mashiach Kelatzy, and I think that this was what I was looking for. Thanks anyway Kavod HaRav!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a sefardi learning about chabad or vice verse. What's the issue here? Everyone needs to find a teacher that speaks to them, this is no different from the general case.

Comment: You could try Rabbi Mansour's shiurim, which are available online in both recorded and written format. He is a leading rabbi in the Brooklyn Syrian community and teaches from a broadly Sephardic viewpoint at itorah.com

Comment: It might be helpful for you to find someone you can study with locally.  It's useful to see with your own eyes how real people practice Judaism in real life.  I wonder what city or town you live in, and whether or not there is a Sephardic synagogue there.  Also:  What were you looking for in your original question?  Online classes, or in-person classes?

Comment: Yes that is a great idea. There is a Sephardi Shul where I live, and they do have shiurim there. Probably will start going there. In my orginal question I was asking about online, but you are totally right that in person would also be beneficial (although do I plan to learn from the beginning).